# Can I add issue status to display near the time a comment was made?

Tags: 2010, task-list, version-history

so i have a task list and a Comments column. For each item if you click on view entries under the comments you get a form with info about the item. where the comments are we have the name of the user, date/time, comment made. In the same spot i want to display also the status that the item had at the time when the comment was made.

example:

john, Do (7/7/2011 10:02 AM): BLALALALAAAALALALLALAL
john, Do (7/6/2011 10:02 AM): BLALALALAAAALALALLALAL
john, Do (7/3/2011 10:02 AM): BLALALALAAAALALALLALAL

after

john, Do (7/7/2011 10:02 AM): BLALALALAAAALALALLALAL  STATUS:RESOLVED
john, Do (7/6/2011 10:02 AM): BLALALALAAAALALALLALAL  STATUS:ACTIVE
john, Do (7/3/2011 10:02 AM): BLALALALAAAALALALLALAL  STATUS:ACTIVE

Is this possible>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, no.  There wouldn't be a way to simply see the previous state of the item when the comment was made.  One way you could accomplish this is by using a SharePoint Designer workflow:

- You could make the comments field not display in the edit form (you can do this in PowerShell or with some third-party tools)
- Add a new column for inputting comments
- When an item is saved, append the new comment to the commends field with the data you want, and then clear the input field

PS to hide a field:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb YOUR_WEB_URL
$list = $web.Lists["YOUR_LIST_NAME"]
$field = $list.Fields["YOUR_FIELD_INTERNAL_NAME"]
$field.ShowInEditForm = $false
$field.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. I will try it and get back